# postgresql: how to select w.r.t to time stamp in different format

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with `created_at` column as `timestamp with time zone`

my database timezone is 'UTC' all times are stored in UTC

I have a time `"2021-01-29 11:30 AM"` of time zone `America/New_York`

now i want it to fetch data using

```
SELECT "id",
       "created_at"
FROM sampletable
WHERE created_at >= (my time at America/New_York)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

so how to user `"2021-01-29 11:30 AM"` of time zone `America/New_York` in the sql to fetch my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id, created_at
  FROM sampletable
 WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2021-01-29 11:30 AM' at time zone 'America/New_York'
 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

You may have a look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) for details.

For other date/time formats like day-month-year you may use [to_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) function.

```sql
SELECT to_timestamp('29-01-2021 11:30 AM', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi AM')::timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York';
```

Comment: `timestamp '2021-01-29 11:30 AM'`  can i have any other format like `day-month-year` and how can i mention